# Django/Python: Filtering a QuerySet twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

`get_messages` returns `messages` shared between two users.

```
def get_messages(self, sender, recipient):
    messages = Message.\
        objects.\
        filter(sender_id=sender.id,
               recipient_id=recipient.id)
    return messages
```

This works fine, but sometimes `User A` will be the `recipient` instead of the `sender` or `User B` will the `sender` instead of the `recipient`.

How can I use `filter` (or some similar function) both ways more eloquently (without calling this function twice with the parameters switched)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) objects to construct complex queries including "OR" conditions.

In this case we can construct two queries with the sender and recipient switched around and "OR" them together

```
filter = Q(sender_id=sender.id, recipient_id=recipient.id)
filter |= Q(sender_id=recipient.id, recipient_id=sender.id)
Message.objects.filter(filter)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could search for messages using the `__in` operator and remove any self posts.

```py
def get_messages(self, sender, recipient):
    ids = [sender.id, recipient.id]
    messages = Message.\
        objects.\
        filter(sender_id__in=ids,
               recipient_id__in=ids).\
        exclude(sender_id = recipient.id )
    return messages
```

Comment: I didn't end up using the `exclude` portion, but list-based operator `__in` worked great.